# Why does decreasing the framerate with videorate incur a significant CPU performance penalty?

Tags: gstreamer

My understanding of the [videorate](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-plugins/html/gst-plugins-base-plugins-videorate.html) element is that framerate correction is performed by simply dropping frames and no "fancy algorithm" is used. I've profiled CPU usage for a gst-launch-1.0 pipeline and I've observed that as the framerate decreases below 1 FPS, CPU usage, counter-intuitively, increases dramatically.[image]
Sample pipeline (you can observe the performance penalty by changing the framerate fraction):

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=test.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videorate drop-only=true ! video/x-raw,framerate=1/10 ! autovideosink
```

I would expect that decreasing the framerate would reduce the amount of processing required throughout the rest of the pipeline. Any insight into this phenomenon would be appreciated.

System info: Centos 7, GStreamer 1.4.5

EDIT: Seems this happens with the videotestsrc as well but only if you specify a high framerate on the source.

```
videotestsrc pattern=snow ! video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=25/1 ! videorate drop-only=true ! video/x-raw,framerate=1/10 ! autovideosink
```

Removing the framerate from the videotestsrc caps puts CPU usage at 1%, and usage increases as the videorate framerate increases. Meanwhile, setting the source to 25/1 FPS increases CPU usage to 50% and it lowers as the videorate framerate increases.

Comment: What are you using to measure the CPU?  What I see as I decrease framerate is most of the time the CPU sits at 0% but has periodic bursts.  When I increase the framerate the CPU usage is more steady but higher than zero.

Comment: ps -p $processPid -o %cpu,
I measure that at 5 Hz then average it

Comment: It seems ps calculates the %CPU for the lifetime of the process. Using the output from top instead gives different results, the average CPU usage over time now seems to be more or less consistent across different framerates, but the bursts are still a concern.

The hope was that I could lower the framerates to improve performance (it should be doing less work) but it appears that it spends nearly half the time idling and half the time at maximum load. How long these periodic bursts of CPU usage are seems to depend on the target framerate.

Comment: Right. You need to think about what is throttling here. In your first case you decode a lot of frames until you decode the frame you want to display. This frame hits the sink but waits for it to display until its timestamp is hit. It will block upstream until the image is shown. Then it can start decoding again . but it again needs a lot frames to decode before it gets a "right" one to the sink. You are in a peak/idle cycle.

Comment: For the second case, add `is-live=true` to the videotestsrc. That should give you a constant 25 fps source. Then you should see that changing the frame rate should not have a high impact on the CPU use. The most expensive task is then to create 25 1080p frame per second. P.S. if you leave out the 25/1 as in your first try here the videotestsrc will pick the 1/10 fps and videorate will be pass through.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tozar I'm going to specifically address the pipeline you posted in your comment above.

If you're only going to be sending a frame once every ten seconds there's probably no need to use h264.  In ten seconds time the frame will have changed completely and there will be no data similarities to be encoded for bandwidth savings.  The encoder will likely just assume a new keyframe is needed.  You could go with jpegenc and rtpjpegpay as alternatives.

If you're re-encoding the content you'll definitely see a CPU spike every ten seconds.  It's just not avoidable.

If you want to place CPU usage as low as possible on the machine doing the transformation, you could go to the work of parsing the incoming h264 data, pulling out the key frames (IDR frames), and then passing those along to the secondary destination.  That would be assuming the original transmitter sent keyframes though (no intra refresh).  It would not be easy.

You may want to form a more general question about what you're trying to do.  What is the role of the machine doing the transformation?  Does it have to use the data at all itself?  What type of machine is receiving the frames every ten seconds and what is its role?

Comment: The feed is coming from some non-specific camera. The purpose of the profiling is to determine the minimum specs required to do the transformation for several different cameras. I'm afraid there isn't a way around re-encoding the content. The transformation is necessary to allow for tuning to optimize for bandwidth or image quality for a low bandwidth link with variable connection quality. On the receiving end is a server that provides the camera stream(s) for monitoring. The tuning can't happen on the camera itself since we will want to record raw video before it goes over the link as well.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will mark one of these answers as correct soon. The goal of this question was to see if lowering the framerate could improve CPU usage, and that doesn't seem to be the case. If the incoming stream was MJPEG already, would lowering the framerate and re-encoding be significantly less expensive?

Comment: Well I wouldn't agree that lowering the framerate won't decrease CPU.  It will depending on how you structure the pipeline, and how you decide to measure CPU activity that is in a peak/idle cycle.  I wouldn't suggest using MJPEG as the first delivery protocol (too much bandwidth) but it may work well as the second delivery protocol with low framerate, downscaled thumbnails for your final viewer application.

Answer (score 1):

`videorate` is tricky and you need to consider it in conjunction with every other element in the pipeline.  You also need to be aware of how much CPU time is actually available to cut off.  For example, if you're decoding a 60fps file and displaying it at 1fps, you'll still be eating a lot of CPU.  You can output to `fakesink` with `sync` set to true to see how much CPU you could actually save.

I recommend adding a bit of debug info to better understand videorate's behavior.

`export GST_DEBUG=2,videorate:7`

Then you can grep for "pushing buffer" for when it pushes:

`gst-launch-1.0 [PIPELINE] 2>&1 | grep "pushing buffer"`

..and for storing buffer when it receives data:

`gst-launch-1.0 [PIPELINE] 2>&1 | grep "storing buffer"`

In the case of decoding a filesrc, you're going to see bursts of CPU activity because what happens is the decoder will run through say 60 frames, realize the pipeline is filled, pause, wait till a `need-buffers` event comes in, then burst to 100% CPU to fill the pipeline again.

There are other factors too.  Like you may need to be careful that you have `queue` elements between certain bottlenecks, with the correct `max-size` attributes set.  Or your sink or source elements could be behaving in unexpected ways.

To get the best possible answer for your question, I'd suggest posting the exact pipeline you intend to use, with and without the videorate.  If you have something like "autovideosink" change that to the element it actually resolves to on your system.

Here are a few pipelines I tested with:

`gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc pattern=snow ! video/x-raw,width=320,height=180,framerate=60/1 ! videorate ! videoscale method=lanczos ! video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=60/1 ! ximagesink`   30% CPU in htop

`gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc pattern=snow ! video/x-raw,width=320,height=180,framerate=60/1 ! videorate ! videoscale method=lanczos ! video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=1/10` 0% with 10% spikes in htop

Comment: gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc uri=udp:///$IP_ADDR:$PORT ! tsdemux ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoscale ! videorate drop-only=TRUE !  video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=1/10 ! x264enc tune=zerolatency bitrate=$BITRATE ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5001 sync=false